# How to update a detached object with a collection inside on EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a detached object which contains a collection. I'm attaching it using this code

```
EntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);
dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Detached object saves perfectly if I change most of the fields.. the issue is with a collection this object has. Changes on the collection are not persisted. I've seen the query executed and it onl touches the "main" table. All dependent relations are not updated

Is there any way to update the entire tree for a detached object?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly set the State for dependent relations as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :**

EF is not aware of the changed `collection` or about the `navigation properties`.By setting the State of the `dbEntityEntry` to `EntityState.Modified`, EF only knows that the object `dbEntityEntry` has been changed. This means that EF will only update `dbEntityEntry` but not it's `navigation properties`.

**Solution :**

You can iterate over all `collection (or navigation properties)` of the current `dbEntityEntry` and set the entity state to `EntityState.Modified`.

**Another Solution :** Please see that too.May be helped to you.

[**Working with Self-Tracking Entities**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Your answer make a lot of sense but it's a pain in the ass to iterate over the entire object tree when it's very deep :(

Comment: Yes,that is true.I have put another solution also.Please see that too.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the way that I found in some framework. Because there are many problems with entity updates, if you use ASP. Before update just call this method

```
 protected virtual void AttachIfNot(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (!_dbSet.Local.Contains(entity))
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
    }
```

For navigation properties, just do same way by iterating in collection.